# Mistake in Java Servlet Specification - Basic Deployment Descriptor Example?

Tags: java, servlets

Reading through the Java Servlet Specification, Version 3.1, Final, April 2013 I noticed that section 14.5.1 "A Basic Example" - "Basic Deployment Descriptor Example" has the following for the web-app declaration tag:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd”
    version=”2.5”>
```

What is odd is that this is for servlet version 2.5.  Section 14.3 does show the new namespace descriptor link.

Am I reading this correctly as a mistake in the final specification document?

Comment: Version 3.1 is backward compatible, no? Also, can you post a link to the doc?

Comment: @Soti: OP is just talking about [JSR340](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340).

Comment: @BalusC Right. A deployment descriptor with version 2.5 is valid for sevlet 3.1, so I would think it's also a valid example for the documentation.

Comment: Any idea why the new spec wouldn't show an example with the new version though?

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.3 uses this language:

> All valid web application deployment descriptors for version 2.3 of this
>   specification must contain the following DOCTYPE declaration:

Version 2.4 uses this language:

> This appendix defines the deployment descriptor for version 2.3. All web containers are required to support web applications using the 2.3 deployment descriptor.

So the precedent was set based on historical releases.

[image: Java Servlet Specification 3.0]

**References**

- [Java Servlet Specification 2.3 (pdf)](https://www.inf.unibz.it/~ricci/MS/Material/servlet-2_3-fcs-spec.pdf)
- [Java Servlet Specification 2.4 (pdf)](http://www.dmi.usherb.ca/~frappier/ift287/servlet-2_4-fr-spec.pdf)
- [Java Servlet Specification 2.5 (pdf)](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/java/api/servlet-2_5-mrel2-spec.pdf)
- [Java Servlet Specification 3.0 (pdf)](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/java/api/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf)
- [UML package diagram example representing most important interfaces and classes of Java Servlet 3.0 API.](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/java-servlet-30-api-package-diagram-example.html)